# Python Multiprocessing function

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a function for example:

```
launcher(usr_login, usr_password)
```

which calls other python script + usr_login + usr_password as arguments.

See:
Function

```
launcher("login", "pass")
```

will execute function.py file as  `$function.py login pass`
Subject:
I have dict user_login : password, And I would like to be able launch a 'launcher' function in one time multithreaded / multiprocessed

dict has login1 : pass1 , login2 : pass2
So I need launch launcher(login1, pass1) and launcher(login2, pass2) in same time.
Is there a way how to do it?
Thank you

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from config import users, ThCount
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

users = {}

def launcher(usr_login, usr_password):
    os.system("C:\\Python34\\python.exe implementation.py %s %s" % (usr_login, usr_password))
```

Reply for comment #1
If I use like this:

```
def launcher(usr_login, usr_password):
    os.system("C:\\Python34\\python.exe implementation.py %s %s" % (usr_login, usr_password))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        p.map(launcher, users)
```

I got:

```
TypeError: launcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'usr_password'
```

Comment: rtfm https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(int(ThCount)) as p:
        p.map(launcher, users)
I tested it before. Doesn't work. Seems like function wasnt called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass multiple arguments to function using `Pool.map()`.

As a simple solution you can pack them into tuple.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

users = {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2',
    'c': '3'
}

def launcher(args):
    os.system("python implementation.py %s %s" % (args[0], args[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as p:
        p.map(launcher, users.items())
```

**UPD** I noticed you're using Python 3.4. Starting from version 3.3 you can use [Pool.starmap](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) to pass multiple parameters and therefore keep list of parameters readable as before.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

users = {
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2',
    'c': '3'
}

def launcher(usr_login, usr_password):
    os.system("python implementation.py %s %s" % (usr_login, usr_password))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as p:
        p.starmap(launcher, users.items())
```

Comment: yeah! Thats I was looking for. You did the solution. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. See UPD part, it's better solution IMHO.

Comment: you can use Pool.starmap to keep it readable as before. What does this mean? 
I have no output. Function just runs Selenium WebDriver and login to site.
Anyway Thank you.

Comment: It allows you to pass few parameters to a function, therefore you can give them readable names, instead of unclear `args`.